# Java8-StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, exception, import

This is my code snippet:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Numrs {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = in.nextInt();
        int pos, i = 1;
        char d;
        while (num <= 10) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            pos = line.length();
            if (line.length() <= 1000000) {

                if (line.charAt(i) == 'R') {

                    line.replace('R', 'K');
                    i++;
                }
                if (line.charAt(i) == 'K') {
                    line.replace('K', 'R');
                    i++;
                }
                num++;

            }

        }

    }
```

It's showing a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when I enter a single digit number like 3, and even if a 2 digit number is entered, it's getting terminated without reading the string. Please help.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: "a 2 digit number is entered, it's getting terminated without reading the string" - any 2 digit number other than 10 will not satify the condition while(num <= 10 )hence it is getting terminated.

Comment: http://www.hackerearth.com/tracks/pledge-2015-easy/number-of-rs-1/

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you enter only one character /digit, then size will be `1` but it will be placed in index `0`. and you are trying to do `line.charAt(i)` where `i=1`

Comment: it's not about size it's about number of test cases <num> and my requirement is to replace R with K and viceversa from position 1 not 0

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems in this approach.
1. The input you need to pass is more than a digit, like `3 this works` because after the 3 your in expects some string.

2. you are not updating `num`. So it will end up in an infinite loop
3. This won't work if you give any value more than 10. I m not sure what you wanted to achieve.
4. Start i from 0, Developers start with 0 :)

Comment: http://www.hackerearth.com/tracks/pledge-2015-easy/number-of-rs-1/ this is what i'm trying to solve so i need to start with i=1and end at i<pos-1 :)